# Angular material тег mat-checkbox зачеркнуть текст при checked true

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Всем доброго времени суток
Есть такой чекбокс:

```
 <section class="example-section">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="func" [checked]="value">
        <span class = "span-check">{{todo?.title}}</span></mat-checkbox>
    </section>
```

Нужно когда чекбокс выбран зачеркнуть написанный текст
Нашла такое решение но оно не работает:

```
.example-margin:checked + .span-check {
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

Comment: Должно работать.. Можно через тот же класс - создаёте класс аля `.text-line-through { text-decoration:line-through; }` и для span добавить `[ngClass]="{'text-line-through' : value}"`

Comment: оно тогда всегда будет зачеркнуто, разве нет?

Comment: если value меняется true|false то не будет всегда зачеркнуто

Answer (score 1):

1. псевдокласс `:checked` работает и должен работать только для элементов с возможностью чекания, то есть, чекбоксов. Белиберда `mat-checkbox` таковым не является - все нестандартные теги браузер трактует так же как обычный span.

В вашем случае поможет селектор атрибутов, например:

```
.example-margin[checked="true"] .span-check {
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

вот только ваш атрибут `[checked]` содержит квадратные скобки, их нужно убрать.

2. оператор `+` в вашем CSS лишний.

Comment: квадратные скобки нужны, иначе ошибка "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'" . данные о checked подгружаются из апи. ваш вариант тоже не зачеркнул надпись(

Comment: не зачеркнул потому, что у меня атрибут `checked`, а не `[checked]`.

Answer (score 0):

Решила вопрос конструкцией ngIf, которая проверяет true или false и в зависимости от результата выводит span нужного класса

```
    <section class="example-section">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="onCheckBoxUpdate(todo.id)" [checked]="todo.is_completed">
        <span class = "span-check" *ngIf="todo.is_completed === true; else unComplete">{{todo?.title}}</span>
        <ng-template #unComplete>
          <span>{{todo?.title}}</span>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-checkbox>
    </section>
```

Решение возможно не очень красивое, буду рада если кто то подскажет лучшее

Comment: лучшее решение - избавиться от бАгомерзкого ангуляра вообще =)